# Update UI on Android networking request using MVP

Tags: android, mvp, okhttp

I'm making a network request inside a Repository class in my Android app. I'm doing this for learning purposes, so I'm trying to understand, without using RXJava, how would I update the UI all the way from my Repository?

The trail of calls goes like so MainActivity -> Presenter -> Interactor -> Repository -> Network

And here is my code in the repository

```
WeatherRepository {
    WeatherNetwork network = new WeatherNetwork();

    public CurrentWeather getCurrentWeather(float lat, float lng) {
        network.getDailyWeather(lat, lng, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try{
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        CurrentWeather currentWeather = getCurrentWeatherData(jsonData);

                    }
                }  catch(JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("DWPresen" + " JSONEXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
                } catch(IOException e){
                    Log.d("DWPresent" + " IOEXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i gave a +1 but you should maybe accept one of the replies or write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho there are two classical ways to do such a thing:

One way would be to pass a callback object down to the repository and call the callback action when you get your response.

The second (and imho more elegant) way would be to use [local broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) in your app. They can be used to transfer messages (like if something happened in your service and you want to notify other threads - like the UI thread - about it.)

There are quite a lot of tutorials about [(local) broadcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager) in android. Normal broadcasts are used to communicate between apps (and between the system and an app), while local broadcasts can be used to just send information within your app.

Comment: went the callback route in this case, but good to know the two options!

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) that works very well with MVP structure.

Briefly, it passes the event(an object with data) from one class to another. In your case, you can pass an event with `CurrentWeather` object inside of it from Repository to Presenter and then update UI.